# AVG installer error

Tags: windows-xp, avg-antivirus

I have a PC running windows-XP-professional. It has been using the free AVG antivirus software without problems for many months. In the last few days the software was pestering me to upgrade to a new (still free) version which I decided to do today. But after performing the requested reboot, I get a window titled "AVG Installer - Error" with the text "A system restart is required in order to continue with the installation. Please restart your system and try again." There is a single "Ok" button on the window. If I then reboot, the exact same window will reappear every time.

Any ideas how I can break out of this endless loop?

**EDIT:** I should mention that while AVG was in the process of downloading and installing, I was, perhaps dangerously, downloading and installing a few other things - like updating to the latest firefox and adobe flash.

**EDIT:** If your answer involves downloading AVG again - then please advise what I should do about the existing half-baked AVG first, should I (could I) try and uninstall it first?

**EDIT:** Looking at the AVG forums, I see that other people have posted similar problems with version 11, but so far there are no replies to their questions :-(

**EDIT:** After looking around the forums some more I found this: http://forums.avg.com/ww-en/avg-free-forum?sec=thread&act=show&id=110317 ... that should fix it.

Comment: +1 for updating a question with a link to something that helped me solve it when I was hit by the same thing. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

### To get rid of the shutdown dialog

(perhaps unsafely)

1. Open Task Manager
2. Find the messagebox dialog in the applications list. If you're not sure you found it, you can test by right clicking on what you think it is and selecting **Bring to Front**.
3. Right click on it and select **Go to Process**. You'll now be in the Processes tab with a process highlighted on the list.
4. Right click on the process and select **Open File Location**.

If it's an AVG-specific file (i.e. if it's in an AVG folder in Appdata or Program Files): Move it to another directory. It won't be able to autorun, but you'll still have it around in case it turns out you need it.

If it's not AVG specific (e.g. it's a DLL) that's a different can of worms.

### To remove the installation

I'm not sure what to do about half-baked installs. If it were me I'd move the content out of Program Files (keep a copy in case you figure out you can, and really should, do something about it - a copy you can move back, etc) then redownload and reinstall it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the left over install manually - it's best not to install over it if you can help it. You can check with support if it's okay. It has worked for me before, but not with this program - not sure but I think you know about the information below.

There are two possible ways to uninstall AVG 9.0 Free Edition:

1. Click on Start > All Programs > AVG 9.0 > Uninstall AVG
2. If you experience any problems with the uninstallation procedure, please follow these steps:

   - Download the latest installation file of AVG from the DOWNLOAD SECTION of our website
   - After downloading, run this file and choose the Uninstall Product option in the dialogue  - Select Setup Type
   - Finish the uninstallation process and restart your computer.

Comment: "There are two possible ways to uninstall".. method 1 does not work because the directory does not exist. Method 2 does not work because as soon as I run the exe I get the dreaded "restart is required" message :-(

Comment: did the other programs install